# Storing typeorm repository function in a variable and calling doesn't works

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I have a typeorm repository function called findOne in a repository called SampleRepository. I am using nestJS and injected the SampleRepository object in the service class. We can invoke that function like

```
function sample(){
    this.sampleRepository.findOne(// relevant code)
}
```

But, when we store that function reference in a variable and use that variable to call findOne, it's throwing an error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'manager')**

```
    const ref = this.sampleRepository.findOne;
    ref(// relevant code)
```

I understand this seems so weird and mindless. But, it's happening. Is there any other parsing happens or am I missing something?

Comment: Yea... It's a mistake in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that the context for the `this` of the `findOne` is being lost. I think you'd need to do `const ref = this.sampleRepository.findOne.bind(this.sampleRepository)` so that later when you call `ref()` you have the proper context. The other option is just don't set the method to a variable reference